# Why does this if statement give me an error

Tags: bash, shell

Can someone explain why this simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

myvar="Hello"

if [[ -z "$myvar" ]]; then
    # echo "It's an unfilled string"
else
    echo "It's a filled string!"
fi
```

gives me the error

```
./testscript: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./testscript: line 7: `else'
```

However, if I remove the comment on the echo line, the script runs fine. Obviously, there is an issue with having commented lines within empty if statements. This this in mind, how do I fix it so I can have an empty if statement with comments?

Comment: Is the `echo` supposed to be commented out?

Comment: Paste your code at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @anubhava: Did you mean `:`?

Comment: @Cyrus: Yes I meant `:` but mistyped it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no statements between `then` and `else`, so this is a syntax error. If you really want to do nothing in the `if` branch, then you can use a `:` (or `true`) as a placeholder:

```
#!/bin/bash

myvar="Hello"

if [[ -z "$myvar" ]]; then
    # echo "It's an unfilled string"
    :
else
    echo "It's a filled string!"
fi
```

Better yet, reverse your logic:

```
#!/bin/bash

myvar="Hello"

if [[ -n "$myvar" ]]; then
    echo "It's a filled string!"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way not to use `if else` statement.

```
#!/bin/bash

myvar="Hello"

[[ -n "$myvar" ]] && echo "It's a filled string!"
```

Also you can use this.

```
#!/bin/bash

myvar="Hello"

[[ -z "$myvar" ]] || echo "It's a filled string!"
```

Comment: or - if `[[ ! -z "$myvar" ]]; then  echo "It's a filled string!"; fi`. +1 for use of **compound command**, but it is nice if you explain that a **compound command** can be used as an alternative to `if ... then .. else .. fi`